# Why is $|x|$ defined as $\sqrt{x^2}$ instead of $(\sqrt{x})^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, absolute-value

I can't seem to understand this even though it might be utterly simple for some people. For me, saying $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ is a bit weird since $\sqrt{x^2}$ **doesn't force positivity** as there are always two possible square roots of a number, 
 $\sqrt{x}=+\sqrt x, -\sqrt{x}$. Then why is it still used everywhere? Is there another way of interpreting this?

I think $|x|=(\sqrt x)^2$ does the job much better.

Comment: What should $|-1|$ be?

Comment: The square root of a positive number $x$ is defined to be the positive real number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. Now, $x^2\geq0$ for any real number $x$...

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ *does* force positivity. It seems to me that you are confusing two concepts 'square roots of $a$' and 'the square root (principal square root) of $a$'.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, that does seem the case, since this is the first time I'm hearing of *principal square root*. It's really sad that none of my teachers told me about this.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma Yes, that is a sad thing. I am glad you asked the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to distinguish two concepts.

- **A square root** of $a$ is any number whose square is $a$. This definition is valid in any number system, not necessarily restricted to non-negative real numbers.

  Also, this definition never tells that such number is unique, and in fact, there are exactly two square roots for a given *non-zero* number either in $\mathbb{R}$ (real numbers) or in $\mathbb{C}$ (complex numbers).
- **The square root** of $a$ for $a \geq 0$ is defined as the unique non-negative square root of $a$. This square root is denoted by $\sqrt{a}$.

  Assuming OP has knowledge on complex numbers, **the principal square root** of a complex number $z$ can be defined as the square root $w$ of $z$ with $\arg(w) \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. This $w$ is denoted as $\sqrt{z}$. It is easy to check that this definition of $\sqrt{z}$ extends the previous one when $z \in [0, \infty)$.

If $x$ is a square root of $a$, then by definition we necessarily have $x^2 = a$. In particular, $(\sqrt{a})^2 = a$ always holds by definition.

Finally, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

- Square roots of $x^2$ are $x$ and $-x$.
- $\sqrt{x^2}$ is the unique non-negative square root of $x^2$.

So if $x \geq 0$, then $x$ is non-negative and $\sqrt{x^2} = x$. If $x \leq 0$, then $-x$ is non-negative and $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$. Combining both cases, we obtain $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $\sqrt{x^2}$ does, in fact, force positivity, because $\sqrt{a}$, where $a$ is a positive number, is defined to be the positive square root.  Yes, $a$ has two square roots, but the positive one is $\sqrt{a}$, and the negative one is $-\sqrt{a}$.

If $x$ is negative, we normally don't write $\sqrt{x}$, because things just got pushed into the complex plane, and roots get crazy their.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is defined for all $x\in\Bbb R$, while $(\sqrt{x})^2$ is defined only for $x\ge 0$. And that's a huge difference.

Furthermore, $|x|$ is not defined as $(\sqrt x)^2$. Instead, $|x|$ is defined as $x$ if $x\ge 0$ and as $-x$ if $x<0$.

Comment: That is true, but it still doesn't prove how $\sqrt{x^2}$ forces positivity.

Comment: I have read various textbooks and Wikipedia as well which states $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma That's correct. Notice that both sides are non-negative, so you can square up both sides to get $|x|^2={(\sqrt{x^2})}^2$ or $x^2=x^2$. This equality is always true.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $\sqrt{x^2}$ is necessarily positive.  There is an implicit + sign.

Secondly, the notation is meant to represent the **magnitude** of a given vector.  Sure, your definition works in the case of a scalar.  But for vector magnitudes(with 2 or more components), your definition breaks down(i. e. $|\binom{x}{y}| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ne (\sqrt{x+y})^2$).